# Yelp Middle UITabBar Navigation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue, yelp

I am trying to do a UX like Yelp's middle UITabBar item with navigation. I saw https://github.com/BasheerSience/BROptionsButton and am using it to get the pop-up UIButtons. However, when I try to navigate to other view controllers from the buttons I can't get anything working. Note, I am using the storyboard. I need a navigation controller since each of the pop-up buttons will navigate to separate VCs. I am probably missing something very basic, but am not seeing it. Thanks!!

Comment: Show your coding part.that is easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came back to this. I ended up using a container view where the ...didSelectItem:(BROptionItem*)item method dictates which child view to navigate to.

I found this to be the most helpful for my situation:
https://github.com/mluton/EmbeddedSwapping